# How to delete messages immediately in OpenPOP

Tags: c#, asp.net, openpop

In openpop we must call disconnect() or disposed() to submit the delete command, how to delete the messages immediately when call pop3Client.DeleteMessage()?

Answer (score 6):

I am a developer for OpenPOP.

The POP3 RFC states that you can send a [`DELE <messagenumber>`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1939#page-8) command to the POP3 server, and the the message with that number will be **marked** as deleted, but only first deleted when the POP3 client enters the `UPDATE` state, which happens when the POP3 client sends the [`QUIT`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1939#section-6) command. When the `QUIT` command is sent, the POP3 client can only disconnect from there. When you call `Disconnect()` on the OpenPOP POP3 client, then the `QUIT` command is sent and the client disconnects. `Dispose()` will internally call `Disconnect()` for you.

This means that **there is no way to delete messages immediately**, since this is how POP3 works.

Comment: Thanks foens!  I was just going through your unit tests to try and figure this out.